# What is error code 100 in facebook api analitics

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

The first i know, is a /page invalid call but,

what is the **second error** on my facebook api analitics?

[image]

Comment: Do you have an app id? I could dive deeper.

Comment: The api id is: 193768273166

Comment: Could it be that you just make a lot of calls to 'graph.facebook.com', without providing an object ID? In your code, do you always check if you have a value for your object before making the call? You should.

Comment: Its a legacy code , with Hundredth o calls, the problem is , this second error does not provide me a node like /page.

Comment: That is because -you don't- provide a node/page. It seems that the call is directly to 'graph.facebook.com'; so no value for the ID. And that will result in error 100.

Comment: Ok, i got it, im looking for that now!